# MS Access inserted new pages to tab control on a form and .oldvalue not working

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a tab control and 6 pages.  I then added some new tabs and the .oldvalue is not captured for any pages from where the new pages were inserted.  The existing process for keeping an audit log of changes which works just fine for the pages up to where the new page is inserted.  Then nothing past that page is being captured.

I've created vba to see what is getting passed to the sub where the audit tracking begins and everything up to the new page shows up nothing from the new page and beyond is being passed.  I had read somewhere that inserting pages can cause problems with a how form remembers things (?) but I can't find where I read that.

I've tried exporting the form to text and re-importing and that didn't solve the problem.  I've also gone as far as recreating the form and tabs and creating the pages in order and then copy/pasting the controls and that didn't work either.  There are now 9 pages and about 150 controls, so I'd hate to have to recreate every control from scratch.  I'm absolutely stumped and can't find anything about this issue. There are also no sub-forms or anything like that going on. (For the record, I've inherited this beast and pretty much forced to work with it without benefit of a full re-design. And yes, on sub-forms and 150 fields in single table. *slaps head*).

Comment: Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was causing the issue, but there were a bunch of controls no longer in use that were set to be not visible.  I'm guessing the reason they weren't deleted is because there was quite a bit of vba controlling those on whether they were activated or not and some other things.  Deleting those and cleaning up the vba seems to have done the trick.  False alarm, everyone.  As you were.